# Azure ARM Template - Resource type Microsoft.Web/serverFarms sku capacity setting to min value causing issues

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Need some help in fixing an issue with ARM Template, we run ARM template as part of our deployment pipeline and during every deployment we end up setting serverfarm sku capacity to 2 as per the section in our template below, we pass `app-server-sku-capacity = 2`.

```js
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
  "name": "[variables('app-server-name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('app-server-sku-name')]",
    "capacity": "[parameters('app-server-sku-capacity')]"
  },
  "properties": {}
}
```

We got auto scaling rules set starting from min 2 instances. When deployment happens under load with more than 2 instances actively running, it executes ARM template and kills all scaled instances and sets the instance count back to 2. This is causing performance issues as all the load is now put on just those two instances. Does anyone know how to set sku.capacity  without affecting scaled instances ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue by not setting sku.capacity, just removed it from my ARM template. Still able to provision the environment successfully, also run as part of our deployment. My ARM template resource looks as below now:

```js
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
  "name": "[variables('app-server-name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('app-server-sku-name')]"
  },
  "properties": {}
}
```